# Prevent duplicate value in database in Doctrine 1.2

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony1

I have a filling form that's work fine.Until recently a user complained of duplicate values being saved in database.Table Lts is related to table2 Koleks in a one to many relationship

action

```
public function executeKolect(sfWebRequest $r){
  $areaId = //code;
  $this->lts = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Lts')->getPaid($areaId, $this->selectedLot);
 if($r->isMethod('post')) {
 //code
 }
foreach($this->lts as $l) {
            $amount = $r->getParameter('amount_received_'.$l['id']);
            $dateOfPayment = $r->getParameter('date_of_payment_'.$l['id'], date('Y-m-d'));
            $startPayment = $l['date_start_of_payment'];//date_of_payment should not less than date_start_of_payment
            $collectionsTable = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Koleks')->getDateCreate($l['id'],$dateOfPayment);
//here i want to make a method to check if the date_of_payment value that i want to insert does not exist yet in the Koleks table related to Lts table
 $koleksTable = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Koleks')->getDateCreate($l['id'],$dateOfPayment);
if ($koleksTable >0) {
                 $this->fieldErrors['date_of_payment_'.$l['id']] = 'exist';  
            }
else {
   //code ..proceed
```

}
     }

now in doctrine table

```
public function getDateCreate($loanId,$datePayment) {
    $q = $this->createQuery('k')
                //->select('k.date_created')
              //  ->from('Koleks k')
                ->innerJoin('k.Lts l')
                ->where('k.l_id=?',$loanId)
                ->andWhere('k.date_created=?',$datePayment);
               //return $q->count();
                $dateCreate = $q->count();
               if ($dateCreate == 1) {
                   $res = $q->fetchAll();
                   return $res;
               }
               else {
                return $dateCreate;
               }
}
```

I want to return an error if a same 'date_created' value is already exist in a Koleks table

But this code will not work..

In my previous project,Using mysqli, I can easily 'avoid' duplicates by using this code

//Action

```
$collectionsTable=$link->getdateCreated($date,$id) 
if $collectionsTable > 0 {
echo "cant proceed"
}
else {
//code to proceed
}
```

//in myclass.php

```
$date = _POST//
function getDateCreate($date) {
    $query  = $this->link->query("SELECT date_created FROM Koleks WHERE date_created = '$date'");
    $rowcount = $query->rowCount();

    if($rowcount == 1) 
    { 
       $result = $query->fetchAll();
       return $result;
    }
    else 
    {
       return $rowcount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code in the Doctrine Table should be (double check the aliases)

```
 public function getDateCreate($loanId,$datePayment) {
    $q = $this->createQuery('k')
                ->innerJoin('k.Lts l')
                ->andWhere('k.l_id = ?',$loanId)
                ->andWhere('k.date_created = ?',$datePayment);
 return $q;
}
```

and in your action

```
//[...]            
$koleksTable = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Koleks')->getDateCreate($l['id'],$dateOfPayment);//GET THE QUERY
$koleksTable->execute(); //EXECUTE THE QUERY
if ($koleksTable->count() >0) {
     $this->fieldErrors['date_of_payment_'.$l['id']] = 'exists';
}
else 
{
     //code ..proceed
}
```